# charts in Partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

I want to create partial views such that each partial view corresponds with one type of chart (say bar chart, pie chart etc.). The chart should be generated on the partial view just by passing the model to it.

I am working on the charts for the first time so not very much aware of the components/libraries available. All the example I seem to find on internet works by creating all the charts at the time of requirement and saving the for further use. Eg. http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-render-chart-object-in-view-in.html#.Uk_r_oaGoUU

Please let me know if any clarification is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching for similar thing I found the following that I think could be helpful to you as well:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1874913.aspx

Comment: I got a same link on another web forum, so I will mark your response as answer.